# What stops water from a moon pool from filling the inside of a submarine?

Tags: pressure, fluid-statics

In some submarines, divers can exit and enter through a moon pool, an opening in the bottom of the submarine.

We can clearly see ocean's water flowing in the moon pool, but it won't come inside.

Why so? What is stopping the water here from coming inside?

[image: a drawing of a submarine with a moon pool]

Comment: You can do this with a cup & a bucket in your house too.

Comment: I am not sure I have ever seen this in a submarine though. If you are more then 10 meters below the surface the water will start to come inside by compressing the air inside...Sounds a little bit risky. Where have you seen this design?

Comment: There is the equivalent of an air lock called an escape trunk. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_trunk

Comment: @valerio92: Submarines _are_ a bit risky. And yes, the water will pressurize the air, whether that's at 1, 10 or 100 meters depth. So?

Comment: @MSalters So this design limits how deep we can go.

Comment: @valerio92: Well, at a certain pressure the air will starts to liquefy. But that's not the depth limit of submarines. The limit for submarines is the hull crush depth.

Comment: @valerio92, the OP is asking about a [moon pool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moon_pool) (also known as a "wet porch" or a "wet room")  It's a feature that has sometimes been built-in to one-of-a-kind research and exploration subs.  Divers sit in the "wet" room, breathing air that is at the same pressure as the water outside, and they can enter and leave the sub through an open hole in the floor.  If it's built for [saturation diving](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saturation_diving), then they can close the hatch and return to the surface while maintaining the same pressure.

Comment: Dupe of : https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/127745/44080

Comment: Sounds a bit like a [diving bell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diving_bell) as well

Comment: Except in very small submarines, where this is done an [airlock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airlock) is employed, so that only a small room needs to be pressurized to the pressure of the surrounding water to prevent the room from flooding.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The air is stopping the water from coming inside.

For the water to enter a cavity already filled with another fluid, it has to either displace or compress this fluid. The shape of the container prevents the air from escaping and the water can't rush in if the air inside is at the same pressure as the water outside, because then the net force on the interface is zero.

Comment: If pressure is equalized, then there is no limit to depth, and they would need decompression chambers going up, and  they would have to store all the compressed air to create the air pressure going down.  Are you assume interface pressure is zero?

Comment: @TonyStewart As far as I understend the sub is a big decompression chamber as the air pressure drops slowly while it emerges.

Comment: @TonyStewart, another possibility has been mentioned in Paparazzi's answer: the chamber where the moon pool is might be the only high pressurized part of the submarine.

Answer (score 8):

Air pressure is what holds back the water. If the air pressure is higher than the water pressure the water cannot enter.  Typically it will just be a pressurized chamber - not the  whole sub.

Comment: No harm in expanding that to a more detailed answer, so far imo, it's just  a comment. There is a bigger audience than just the OP, and I was told this myself recently, (and it's a perfectly valid point to make), for one of my own  answers :) thus this comment   .

Comment: -1 for lack of detail. Happy to upvote if you add more detail.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airlock

Answer (score 6):

As someone else has said, the air pressure is what prevents the water from entering the submarine. But let's do some calculations.

We will assume that the robustness of the hull is not a problem, i.e. the hull of the submarine can withstand infinite pressure$^1$.

The pressure inside is initially $P_{atm}=1$ atm. The pressure outside (water pressure) can be computed from the [hydrostatic equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrostatic_equilibrium):

$$P_{out}(z) = P_{atm} + \rho g z$$

Let's assume that the air inside can be approximated by an ideal gas; we will then have

$$P_{in} = nRT/V$$

whre $V$ is the volume of air inside the moon pool chamber. We will also assume that the internal temperature $T$ is kept constant by a very efficient air conditioning system.

With the submarine design you show, mechanical equilibrium requires that

$$P_{out}=P_{in}$$

from which we obtain

$$V(z) = \frac{nRT}{P_{atm}+\rho g z}$$

The initial volume is

$$V^*=\frac{nRT}{P_{atm}}$$

from which

$$V(z)  = V^* \cdot \left(1+\frac{\rho g z}{P_{atm}}\right)^{-1}$$

This equations tells us how the volume of air inside the chamber decreases with depth.

For water, we have $\rho=10^3$ kg/m$^3$ and this value can be considered independent from $z$ since water is almost incompressible. Atmospheric pressure is $P_{atm}=10^5$ Pa. We round up $g$ to $10$ m/s$^2$. Therefore we obtain

$$V(z)  \simeq V^* \cdot \left(1+\frac{z}{10 \text m}\right)^{-1}$$

At $10$ meters deep, $V \simeq V^*/2$.

At $20$ meters deep, $V \simeq V^*/3$...

You can see that very soon the room will be completely filled with water. In order to prevent this, it must be pressurized, and this requires the use of an airlock. But even like this, the pressure in the chamber cannot be increased too much, otherwise those who enter will risk [oxygen intoxication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxygen_toxicity).

---

$1.$ This is not such a bad approximation as it seems. Modern nuclear submarines [can go as deep as $730$ m](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Submarine_depth_ratings) before the hull collapses, withstanding a pressure of $74$ atmospheres. A submarine with a hole in it will be filled in water well before the hull collapses (see above discussion).

Comment: A sub has facilities to increase air pressure.

Comment: @Paparazzi Sure, but there is still a limit since the human body cannot withstand arbitrary pressures.

Comment: Then they could not stand the water pressure either so that is mute?

Comment: @Paparazzi I analyzed the situation of a submarine with an hole in it. Then, we can discuss as much as we want about submarines in real life.

Comment: Real live human body is in scope but pressurize the sub is out of scope?

Comment: @Paparazzi No, neither is :-) What I mean is, I think that my analysis is correct. After that, we can discuss real-life implications. I just wanted to cut here this discussion because it is out of the scope of my answer to discuss the working of real life submarines. Peace!

Comment: "It's common for saturation divers to live under pressure for weeks if not months at a time beyond a pressure of 1000 feet of seawater, but typically not more than 1500 feet. I believe **the limitations are more economical rather than physiological**. " - That's the best answer (actually just a comment) we've got so far on, [Highest Pressure Human Body Can Survive In?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/21252/highest-pressure-human-body-can-survive-in) *"the human body cannot withstand arbitrary pressures"* [citation needed]

Comment: *Let's see how deep you can go underwater with a design of this kind* (one that continually increases the pressure to keep the water out, **and you still be alive**). I was looking forward to *that* answer...

Comment: hi @valerio92 I am not **Physicist** to understand your Equations. please edit your answer.